Are async, await a replacement for process.nexttick()?
https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#why-use-processnexttick
I read about process.nexttick() in the official Nodejs documentation above. According to the documentation, process.nexttick is used for 2 main reasons

Allow users to handle errors, cleanup any then unneeded resources, or perhaps try the request again before the event loop continues.

At times it's necessary to allow a callback to run after the call stack has unwound but before the event loop continues.


To summarize, I believe that ensuring execution order is key, but if so, has await and async come along and replaced that role?
The example below is from process.nexttick.
// Without process.nexttick()
const EventEmitter = require('node:events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.emit('event');
  }
}
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});

// With process.nexttick()
const EventEmitter = require('node:events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // use nextTick to emit the event once a handler is assigned
    process.nextTick(() => {
      this.emit('event');
    });
  }
}
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});


The alternative is await null. The timing may be different due to how they work internally. This is potential XY problem because it's generally a bad practice to put asynchronous side effects to a constructor.

It would probably be more correct to say that nextTick has been superseded by Promise. They indeed are both microtasks, serving the same purposes. While this is mainly true for front-side, similar situations can arise also on the server side, but one such purpose is to handle synchronous events in a batch. So if something emits an event every time it's been modified, you might want to only handle the last state and not every events. (e.g. MutationObserver is one such case in the DOM).

According to https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#understanding-processnexttick :
Nexttick exists for users who wish to provide async APIs to their code, but that code actually is not async.
The normal use case for async/ await is for example, when doing disk operations, you do not wish these operations to be blocking (remember that JS is a non-blocking language), so by calling async functions, the programmer delegates the work of checking if new data is ready to be processed to the event loop. In the poll phase, if there is new data, the event loop will execute the callbacks defined in user code, but if there isn't, no user code has to run, speeding up execution.
Let's say that I want to write a library that offers an API similar to that of a file, on which you normally process things asynchronously, but that because of some reason (there isn't any actual async operations to do, speed, implementation details, hardware limitations on low-power or portable platforms, communication protocol weirdness), I can't wait for the next loop to occur. This is the use-case of process.nexttick.
This is also true of the other use-case you mentionned, for example if a communication protocol expects you finish the dataframe you've partially built before you send the next one, it would be a valid use case (though convoluted) for process.nexttick to catch any exceptions and properly finish the frame.
In general, it is ill advised to use process.nexttick in production. I've found that for all use-cases of it, either javascript was not an appropriate tool for the job, or other, more user-friendly APIs exist with a behavior similar enough that dealing with the hassle of process.nexttick is not worth it.
